# UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined

Tags: javascript, discord, discord.js

This is my index.js and my getting this error(UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: TypeError: Cannot read property 'play' of undefined),can u help me?

```js
const Discord = require("discord.js"),
client = new Discord.Client(),
settings = {
    prefix: "=",
    token: "(my bot's token)"
};
 
const { Player } = require("discord-player");
const player = new Player(client);
client.player = player;
client.player.on('trackStart', (message, track) => message.channel.send(`Now playing ${track.title}...`))
 
client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log("I'm ready !");
});

client.on("message", async (message) => {
 
    const args = message.content.slice(settings.prefix.length).trim().split(/ +/g);
    const command = args.shift().toLowerCase();

 if (command === "play") {
     let track = await client.Player.play(member.voice.channel, args[0], message.member.user.tag);
     message.channel.send(`Currently playing ${track.name}! - Requested by ${track.requestedBy}`);
 }
});
client.login(settings.token);
```

Answer (score 0):

Remember that JavaScript variable names are case sensitive. Compare the following lines from your example:

```js
client.player = player;
let track = await client.Player.play();
```

Try changing your calls to `client.player` instead of `client.Player`.

You may even want to rename `player` to `currentPlayer` or something, to differentiate `player` (an instance) from `Player` (a class).

Comment: I did and now i got this error: (node:208) UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: ReferenceError: member is not defined

Comment: Looking at your example, you don't define `member` anywhere. What do you expect to happen in this case? Where should `member` be defined?

Comment: fr,i'm new to js,be easy on me brother. u can just tell me sir

Comment: You are trying to reference a variable named `member`, however this is not defined, as the error message states. You need to define `member` before you can use it.

Comment: how can i define it?

Comment: That's not really something anyone can answer for you. What should the value you? Where does the value come from?